# Input Function and returning number of words in dataset

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

I'm supposed to be writing a function for an input of any word to search in the song title and then return the number of songs that contain the word. If no word found then return a statement saying no words found. My output is running the `elif` statement and then my `if` statement. I'll post what my outlook is looking like.

```
import csv
word_count = 0
with open("billboard_songs.csv") as data:
    word = input("Enter any word: ")
    for line in data:
        line_strip = line.split(",")
        if word.casefold() in line_strip[1]:
            word_count += 1
            print(word_count, "songs were found to contain", word.casefold(), "in this data set")
        elif word_count == 1:
            print("No songs were found to contain the words: ", word.casefold())
```

Current output:

> No songs were found to contain the words: war
>
> No songs were found to contain the words: war
>
> No songs were found to contain the words: war
>
> No songs were found to contain the words: war
>
> 2 songs were found to contain war in this data set
>
> 3 songs were found to contain war in this data set
>
> 4 songs were found to contain war in this data set
>
> 5 songs were found to contain war in this data set
>
> 6 songs were found to contain war in this data set
>
> 7 songs were found to contain war in this data set
>
> 8 songs were found to contain war in this data set

Comment: Well you're checking each line individually, sounds like you want to check over all the lines and sum them. E.g. `sum([word in song for song in csv_file])`?

Comment: where would I put the sum?

Comment: Well, try `sum([word.casefold() in line.split(",")[1] for line in data])`.

Comment: okay and where would I insert that? @Adam I'm sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issues with the code.

- You should be using the `csv` library you've already imported, not splitting on comma `,`.
- Your `if` statement really isn't doing what you might expect.

You should do something similar to the following:

```
import csv  # Use it!
```

Store the word as a variable:

```
word = input("Enter any word: ").casefold()
```

Hopefully your CSV has headers in it... use `csv.DictReader` if it does:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('billboard_songs.csv', 'r'))
```

Iterate through each song in the CSV... from `line_strip[1]`, it looks as if your song lyrics are in the second field. So loop through those. You should also set up a variable to store the count of songs containing the word at this stage:

```
word_count = 0
for lyrics in reader['song_lyrics']:  # replace 'song_lyrics' with your CSV header for the field with song lyrics
    # Check the word is present
```

Iterate through the full CSV first, before printing output.

```
    if word in lyrics:
        word_count += 1
```

Once that finishes, you can use an `if`/`else` statement to print any desired output:

```
if word_count == 0:
    print('No songs were found to contain the words: {}'.format(word))
else:
    # at least one set of lyrics had the word!
    print('{} song(s) were found to contain {} in this data set'.format(word_count, word))
```

Or, instead of the for loop and everything else below `reader`, you could use `sum` as follows:

```
word_count = sum([word in lyrics for lyrics in reader['song_lyrics'])
```

Then you could just use a generic `print` statement:

```
print('There were {} songs that contained the word: {}'.format(word_count, word))
```